# Double subscript issue

Tags: math-mode

How can I write (Jx)x∈A in LaTeX? (the second subscript is for parentheses.)

I am trying to write like this, but it's not working: `(J}_x)_{x_\in_\textit{A}`

Thank you!

Comment: Hm, difficult to see, what you like to obtain. Maybe $J(x)_{x\in A}$ (this very unusual notation)? I only guessing ... And of course: Welcome to SE!.

Comment: Well @Zarko, I've already seen that notation for mathematical sequences but with u,n and N not J,x and A so yes that's quite strange in fact!

Comment: @PMC1234, to me is more logical $J(x\in A)$ or $J_{x}\big|_{x\in A}$, however, different topics areas, different habits ...

Comment: Yeah! I got a look on Wikipedia and it differs from countries ! In France we use this notation (u_n)_n\inN, and in anglophone countries they use yours !

Comment: I very rarely read french literature (only with lot of pictures, they doesn't require language knowledge :-) ), so in OP question is actually wrong the first`}` after letter `J`. She only need to remove it.

Comment: @Zarko -- please make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out `${(J_x)}_{x\in A}$`. It works with me.

Comment: You are completely right! But when it tends to be separated expressions, they are mandatory so, let's use them every time :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will obey Barbara Beeton suggestion:

- in your code are misplaced curly braces and use of `_`: instead of `(J}_x)_{x_\in_\textit{A}` it should be `$(J_x)_{x\in\textit{A}}$ or simpler $(J_x)_{x\in A}$
- your notation is very unusual, to me is more logical `$J(x\in A)$` or `$J_{x}\big|_{x\in A}$` or even `$J_{x\in A}$`.

See examples below:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{preview}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
\verb+$(J_x)_{x\in A }$+: &    $(J_x)_{x\in A}$\\
\verb+$J(x\in A)$+:              &  $J(x\in A)$\\
\verb+$J_{x}\big|_{x\in A}$+:    &  $J_{x}\big|_{x\in A}$\\
\verb+$J_{x\in A}$+:             &  $J_{x\in A}$
    \end{tabular}
    \end{preview}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```

[image]